# How can I automatically delete /tmp folder on shared drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, powershell

We have a /tmp folder that people use for temporary stuff. It can be anything and any file.

We want to make it so that this automatically deletes (or preferably MOVES to another folder on the same shared drive) all the files that haven't been accessed in the last two weeks. This should happen weekly on a schedule that I don't have to manually do.

Is there software out there that does this? Anyone have a script possibly?

Server 2008R2

Comment: Where are you going to move the files to? Another folder? Another Windows Server? A Linux server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
get-childitem -Path "<location of tmp folder>" |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-15)} | 
    move-item -destination "<destination>"
```

This Powershell script will move the files older than 2 weeks.

Comment: +1 Pop into a `tmp_clean.ps1` file, set Task Scheduler to run it every night an hour before the backup window starts.